# Python - how to read Sharepoint excel sheet without authentication

Tags: python, excel, pandas, authentication, sharepoint

I just want to read a excel file in Sharepoint, but with no authentication.

Read a sharepoint excel file using the file link, without a authentication.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to authenticate (or program the authentication in), to download, you can try requests.get(url="link")
or you could use selenium, to browse the website, and download the file.
And then you can open it with pandas.